# click event is not working in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My scenario is - after login, dashboard page is displaying ,there I want to click on a link. which will give a `javascript` popup. Though my `xpath` is correct it is not clicking on it. And the test is also showing pass.
I have attached both `html` and `selenium` code -

Html :

```
<!-- create connection section -->
    <section class="wrangler-create-project left-align">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn z-depth-0" data-target="create-project-modal"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle left" aria-hidden="true"></i>New project</a>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Selenium Code :

```
@Test
 public void clickNewProject() throws TimeoutException
 {
            UtilsMethods.login();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(UtilsMethods.driver, 40);
            System.out.println(UtilsMethods.driver.getPageSource());
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.xpath("//a[@data-target='create-project-modal']")));
            UtilsMethods.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-target='create-project-modal']")).click();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='project_name']")));
  }
```

Comment: Show your exception log

Comment: Add all the things related to the answer. It would be more useful to answer.

Comment: @ChathuraHennayaka is it the problem as i  am testing application on local. The application is django application ,which i am running locally .Do I need to deploy it in a server then test ?

Answer (score 0):

we can keyboard action events,

UtilsMethods.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-target='create-project-modal']")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter)

Comment: Use the Actions for eg:

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.sendKeys(Keys.Enter).perform()/click();

Comment: //div[@class='container']/descendant::a[contains(@class,'btn')]

or

//div[@class='container']/descendant::a[contains(@data-target,'create-project-modal')]